# Rename Attribute Members in SSAS

Tags: ssas

In my database, I have a Date table with a Quarter column.  This contains the integers 1, 2, 3, or 4.  Structurally, everything in my cube is fine, but rather than just displaying the numbers, I would like to display Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4.

Is there any way to rename the members so that they are prefixed with a Q.  I could add a name column to my database, but it would be better if I could just do it in the cube.

I have tried putting "Q" and "Q"0 into the format string, but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named calculation in the Data Source View to do this. See the documentation for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174859.aspx